# Integral equation corresponding to initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Question is to :

Form an integral equation corresponding to the initial value problem
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0 ~; ~ x>0$$ with initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$

What i have tried so far is :

Put $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\psi(x)$$

I use fundamental theorem of calculus $$\int_a^b f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$$ where $F$ is anti derivative of $f$.

In this case we would have

$$\int_0^x\psi(t)dt=\int_0^x \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}dt=F(x)-F(0)=\frac{dy}{dx}-y'(0)$$

i.e., $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\int_0^x\psi(t)dt+y'(0)$$

i.e., $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\int_0^x\psi(t)dt$$

But i am confused how to get $y$ from this (though i am sure i should use same fundamental theorem of calculus)....

If I got $y(x)$ then I would just substitute that in differential equations to get integral equation.

Please do not write whole answer at once... I would like to get some hints and try to learn something before concluding for an answer.

Kindly co operate with me..

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the following relation?
$$\psi (x)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-y$$

Letting $D$ be differential operation, we have
$$(D^2y)+y=0\Rightarrow (D^2+1)y=0\Rightarrow (D-i)(D+i)y=0$$
This means that letting $z=(D-i)y=Dy-iy=y^\prime-iy$, then $(D+i)z=0$.

Namely, $Dz+iz=0\Rightarrow z^\prime+iz=0.$

Do you think you can continue?

Comment: yes yes.. this does makes lot of sense but my concern was actually to find general procedure.... If you know $\psi(x)=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ then i could calculate what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is... Now what would be $y(x)$ in general set up..

Comment: Well, how about using differential operation $D$?

Comment: I am not familiar with that operation... could you please explain a bit more in detail..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I added a bit. You should continue the last step.

Comment: $z'=-iz\Rightarrow z(x)=e^{-ix}$ This is fine..But then what wold be there after? Consider $z=(D-i)y\Rightarrow e^{-ix}=(D-i)y$ and then?

Comment: So, we get $y^\prime -iy=Ce^{-ix}$. Then, multiplying $e^{-ix}$ to the both sides gives us $(ye^{-ix})^\prime=Ce^{-2ix}\Rightarrow ye^{-ix}=(C/(-2i))e^{-2ix}+E\Rightarrow y=(C/(-2i))e^{-ix}+Ee^{ix}$. Thus, changing $C$ to $-2iC$ gives us that $y=Ce^{-ix}+Ee^{ix}$. Then, since $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$,$\cdots$

Comment: $y=A\cos x -iB \sin x$.. But this is not what i want i guess... I want $y(x)$ to be in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=\int_0^x\psi(t)dt+y'(0)$ and then I would substitute $y(0)$ to get $y(x)$.. This is how it should have been.... I am sorry..

Comment: Never mind. Maybe I gave you what you don't want though my way is one of the solutions.